# Optimal number of clusters using big datasets (Fastcluster)

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have started using the Fastcluster package for clustering a big dataset (>100000 obs., 12 variables, but I selected the three "most informative"). I have the problem of how to obtain the optimal number of clusters.
It worked fine, but now I want to estimate the optimal number of clusters. In my double-step approach, I used cluster.stats() (fpc) and NbClust() (NbClust) for obtaining different statistics to decide, but I cannot do that with my big dataset because they require a distance matrix (cluster.stats) or need to compute it internally (NbClust). I might be wrong, but I believe that it would require 45 GB of memory even if considering one of the triangles.

Before testing Fastcluster, I was using a two-step approach by clustering each of my samples (200-1000 obs.) using agnes() (agglomerative clustering, cluster package), obtaining the centroids and using agnes with these centroids, then reassigning the cluster membership.
With Fastcluster, I used hclust.vector() in a single step. I could not use fastcluster::hclust since it requires calculating a distance matrix.
My current solution was hacking NbClust (insternally using hclust.vector and similar memory-saving tricks when necessary and also ignores all the statistics requiring distances calculation; e.g., Silhouette, Hubert's).
My question is if you know of any approach for evaluating the optimal number of clusters with these big datasets or either if there is any way to generate distance matrices with a limited amount of memory.
Of course, I could go on with my tricked NbClust (which can calculate a dozen statistics) and critically evaluate the different clustering structures, but just curious in case I have overseen a suitable package or already posted solution (thanks in advance!)